# Is the following a vector space with not regular scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The set of $x=[x,y,z]$ over field $R$ such that we have **normal vector addition**, but scalar multiplication as follows:

$k[x,y,z]=[kx,ky,z]$

Basically you only multiply the first two elements.

This doesn't seem like a vector space, but I was having a hard time finding a counter example. Is this indeed a vector space?

Comment: Is it $(\alpha+\beta)(x,y,z)=\alpha(x,y,z)+\beta (x,y,z)?$

Comment: $z$ is the problem, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the addition is the normal vector addition, then the $0$ element of this adition is $(0,0,0)$. Therefore, you should have$$(\forall k\in\mathbb{R})(\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^3):0.v=(0,0,0).$$But we don't have that, since, for instance $0.(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)$. Therefore, what you have is *not* a vector space.